# ¿Cómo mando llamar mi base de datos (creada con SQL Server alojada en un servidor remoto) con mi Web Service (ASP.NET)?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, webservice, vscode

Estoy desarrollando un Web Service con (ASP.NET) del tipo REST, tengo mi base de datos desarrollada con SQL Server alojada en un servidor remoto, actualmente mi web service intenta hacer una petición get a la base de datos y me aparece un error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> SqlException: El nombre de objeto 'Movil_Usuarios' no es válido.
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.b__209_0(Task result)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo cuando hago la misma petición a una base de datos que tengo de forma local en mi computadora no hay ningún problema, me da la información en formato JSON.

Adjunto aquí mis clases importantes:

Archivo de configuración de Cadena de conexión:

```
    {
      "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Information",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
        }
      },
      "AllowedHosts": "*" ,
      
      "ConnectionStrings": { 
        "DBConnection" : "Server=servidorIP,1433,Database=prueba;User=UserPrueba;Password=;Encrypt=False"
      }
    }
```

Clase de contexto:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace UsuarioApi.Models
{
    public class UsuarioContext : DbContext
    {
        public UsuarioContext(DbContextOptions<UsuarioContext> options) : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<Movil_Usuarios> Movil_Usuarios { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Demostración de funcionalidad de forma local:

> **NOTA:** Realice la misma base de datos, con el mismo nombre de tabla, los mismos campos y la misma configuración, la base de datos ya tiene la configuración de conexiones remotas ya que anteriormente teníamos conectada una aplicación Android directamente.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*" ,
  
  "ConnectionStrings": { 
    "DBConnection" : "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Oracle2;Trusted_Connection=True;Encrypt=False;"
  }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba los siguiente; a tu cadena de conexión:

```
"ConnectionStrings": { 
   "DBConnection" : "Server=servidorIP,1433,Database=prueba;User=UserPrueba;Password=;Encrypt=False"
}
```

en la parte donde indicas el puerto tienes a continuación `,` (coma) debe ser  `;` (punto y coma). Lo anterior entre el `1433` y `Database`.

```
"ConnectionStrings": { 
   "DBConnection" : "Server=servidorIP,1433;Database=prueba;User=UserPrueba;Password=;Encrypt=False"
}
```

Comment: Ya quedo muchas gracias !!! fuiste de gran ayuda enserio !!!

Comment: @esmeraldavelazquez suele ocurrir que de tanto estar codificando esos detalles no los notamos.